# How can I create a "game over" image zoom into the screen using HTML & Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently developing a HTML game for one of my programming classes and I want to add a "game over" screen that will display an image and information on their score before dying.

What I would like to happen is for the image to overlay the body of the page and start small in the middle of the screen and "expand" or zoom into the screen to a specific size. I'm not sure if that's clear but here is what I'm sort of looking for: 
[image]

But I would like it to zoom in rather than just appear. Any links or help would be greatly appreciated because I don't even know what to search on google to get information on this!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Look into CSS3 transforms, specifically translate and scale.

Comment: It's always apreciated it you, at least, try to achieve what you want before asking "how to do it" and show your code "not working". Often it leads to people thinking (I hope this is not the case) that posters are just  asking others to make the code for them not even trying to make an effort.

Comment: Ditto to what @AlvaroMenéndez said. Especially when you say that you're doing this for a class (or work for that matter). You shouldn't expect the internet to do your homework for you. I understand in this case you might be adding that part as a sort of extra credit bit to your mostly finished product, but it still doesn't hurt to give it a shot first.

Comment: This question really shows no effort on the asker's end... Stackoverflow is not a website where others will do your coding for you. You're welcome to get help with **your** code, but don't expect us to write it all for you. Also, if this is for a class and you're just looking for a quick *givemetehcodez* answer, then you're not really *learning* anything...

Answer (score 1):

It's really rough but you can do something like this:

JS

```
var $foo = $('#foo');

grow = function (size) {
    if (size < 50) {
        console.log(size);
        $foo.css('width', size + '%');
        $foo.css('height', size + '%');
        size++;
        setTimeout(grow, 10, size);
    }
}

grow(0);
```

CSS

```
#foo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a05s1a44/

Change the timeout length to control the speed. Adjust the CSS as needed. Scale the size variable for the dimensions of your box. Change the limit. Do whatever. Should be enough to get you going.

Comment: You could do that in CSS with transitions as well - no javascript needed apart from toggling the class to open it.

Answer (score 0):

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/shfv0b3f/

Using transform: scale and transition:

```
div {  
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

On game over:

```
div.zoom {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have made for you and I hope it would help.

basically in a container which it may be the window of your game, I have added the "game over" container you want to show.

The rest of the html is just so you see some false content inside game container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="stuff">and here is stuff</div>
    <div class="stuff">etc, ect, ect</div>
    <div class="stuff">more text</div>
    <div class="stuff">and more</div>
    
    <div class="button">Click here</div> 
    
    <div class="this-is-your-game-over"></div>
    
</div>
```

You can see there's also a class called `button` that I have used as to trigger the "game over" container zoom effect. In your game development you may use something else to do it.

Then, basically, you will have a "game over" container positioned as this:

```
.this-is-your-game-over {
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    background-color:blue;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    margin: auto;     
}
```

so It is always centered and by jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.button').click(function () {
                $('.this-is-your-game-over').toggleClass("this-is-your-game-over-ADDED");                
                
            });
        });
```

When you click on button you add another class to the "game over" container that will make it grow to your desire size with a simple transition:

```
.this-is-your-game-over-ADDED {
    height:80%;
    width:50%;  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

This is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/zutLsj67/2/)** to see verything in action

important: If in your html the `this-is-your-game-over` div is not at the end of your html you may need to add a positive `z-index`to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect use case for CSS transitions and transforms.

Very basically:

```
#image {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#image.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Then you just toggle the `.hidden` class somehow, probably by JS.
Also, don't forget to add vendor prefixes (or use Autoprefixer).

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waaMvM for better example.